# SQL CONTAINS returning no results on a FullText-indexed column?

Tags: mysql

Trying to fix performance of a Wordpress file-managing plugin I've been using. Contains over 10,000 rows and much of its purpose is to be text-searched.

The plugin was using `LIKE %abcabc%` for searches, which from my understanding (which there is little) completely negates the benefits of a FULLTEXT index on the columns, correct?

So I've replaced the `LIKE %abcabc%` with a `CONTAINS(column, 'term')` but am getting no results.

This image should show what's what, anything wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on below mySql documentation, there is no function CONTAINS.  The equivalent function that you want is MATCH() AGAINST(text in Boolean Mode).

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html

```
Select *
From `wp_wpfb_files`
Where match(file_description) against('nemesis' in boolean mode)
```

Comment: thanks, this was it, figured it would yell at me for using a function that doesn't exist, guess not